# Proper implementation NRT in ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, c#-8.0, nullable-reference-types

I have few question about nullable reference types as part of C# 8.0 in ASP.NET Core MVC:

1. When exist action with string parameter (`public IActionResult Index(string message)`) then parameter can be still null if is not passed to action. What is official solution to that problem? Still need to check null?
2. When exist simple mutable model how can be properly modyfied to NRT? For example Scott Allen (https://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2019/08/07/think-twice-before-returning-null.aspx) propose to create `NullUser`. Is it correct? `Maybe<T>` sound also do not fitted for NRT. What is official solution for mutable and immutable models?

   ```
   public class User
   {
       public int UserId { get; set; }
       public string FirstName { get; set; }
       public string LastName { get; set; }
       public IEnumerable<Message> Messages { get; set; }
   }

   public class Message
   {
       public int MessageId { get; set; }
       public string Text { get; set; }
   }
   ```
3. Now very often i use `FirstOrDefault` when want pull something from collections (and after check null). Collection is not null but can be empty and now when want to use `First` will thrown an exception what is bad cuz it is a action and want create just bad response without try (https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/387674/c-8-non-nullable-references-and-the-try-pattern) and try-catch. Again `Maybe<T>` sound not as solution. What is official solution for this problem?

I know i do not need to avoid nulls but want to minimalize them and follow NRT cuz its sound like song of future

Answer (score 2):

You're making this far too difficult. Nullable reference types are just a compiler hint - a way of being more explicit about what you actually expect a piece of code to do. It really doesn't change how anything works.

For example, with the situation of an action param. If your `string` param can be null (not *should* be, but *can* be - that's important), then it should be `string?` instead. Action params are almost always optional, so they can certainly be null. The only exception is route param, since you won't actually arrive at this action unless the route param is filled with something. Assuming it's being filled via the query string, for example, then it can definitely be null, and you should use `string?` there. If you want to ensure that it's not null, then you'll need to employ a standard null guard:

```
if (message == null)
    return BadRequest();
```

Mutability also has nothing to do with this. Again, all you're doing is being explicit about whether a reference *could* be null. This also applies to your third question. There's always a potential that a query won't match a row in the database, which will then return null. Using `First` is not some way of ensuring that actual value is returned; it will simply throw an exception in that case, instead. In this situation, you should continue using `FirstOrDefault`, use `User?`/`Message?` (or just `var`), and then do a null check as you always have.